# Duplicate dropdown menu showing up on mobile, but not on any other page?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

http://testserver.davidbenrimon.com/artists.html

The second dropdown menu (in mobile view) appears on this particular page but no others, I've tried everything. How do I remove it?

Comment: Is this just a static page? It's appearing in code twice.

Comment: It's not appearing like that in the html doc, there's only one nav. But when inspecting the code on the online site, it shows two "responsive-nav" classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have added your scripts and closing body and html tags twice, which is causing the mobile menu to be created twice.

[image: Screenshot of duplicate code in source.]

Comment: Found this out earlier, it's always the obvious things missed! Thanks!